# Get unbalanced row from query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

The scenario is DD is deposit details having its own id and D is the actual deposit. Details consist of activities performed on deposits.

```
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|      DD     |     D     |    AMOUNT    |    MEMBER    |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       1     |     1     |    1500.00   |       2      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       2     |     1     |   -1500.00   |       2      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       3     |     1     |     350.00   |       4      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       4     |     2     |    1000.00   |       5      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       5     |     2     |   -1000.00   |       5      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       6     |     3     |     100.00   |       5      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       7     |     3     |     -10.00   |       5      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
```

The objective is to get row 3 only as it has details of the unbalanced amount. My version of query to exclude balanced amount

```
SELECT dd,d,amount,SUM(amount) FROM test 
group by dd
having sum(amount)>0
```

It doesnt seem to be working. Also SQL Fiddle is down so I am unable to give a proper example. I found [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rWm4V3L5AY2jLfTdHXfRqE/0) but above example doesnt seem to execute there.

Also can anybody tell what type of query would this be?

**EDIT**

Expected Output:

```
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|      DD     |     D     |    AMOUNT    |    MEMBER    |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       1     |     1     |    1500.00   |       2      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       2     |     1     |   -1500.00   |       2      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       3     |     1     |     350.00   |       4      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       6     |     3     |     100.00   |       5      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|       7     |     3     |     -10.00   |       5      |
|-------------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
```

Comment: You should probably be looking at member rather than dd.

Comment: @P.Salmon the above example is an ideal one .. for row 2 member Id can be 3 or 5 .. So to get details I focused on dd

Comment: So every positive amount should be followed by a balancing negative amount (in dd order)?

Comment: @P.Salmon ok so just received a word my expected output has changed let me post it and I will work on it simultaneously ..

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
select * from tbl
where d in (
    select d from tbl
    group by d
    having sum(amount) <> 0
);
```

Subquery will return only unbalanced `D`s, outer query will filter out balanced `D`s based on result of subquery.